# Multiple DateTimePicker form array in React Native (Open DateTimePicker once at a time)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, datetimepicker

I am new in React Native. I have  one array with date and display dates.
I have one issues in my code. When I open one date picker its also open other date picker.

So, How to open only one date picker at a time. Help me devs.

I am used this library @react-native-community/datetimepicker.

This is output my code.[Not actual behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R78NJ.png)

If you are any solution please let mw known.

Here is my code.

Array:

```
var Data = [
  {Id: 1, name: 'ajay', date: '21/02/2021'},
  {Id: 2, name: 'vijay',date: '12/02/2022'},
  {Id: 3, name: 'zoya',date: '04/05/2023'},
]

const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    const currentDate = selectedDate;
    setDate(currentDate);
  };

const showDatepicker = () => {
    setShow(true);
  };

<View style={{marginTop:50}}>
      {
        Data.map((d, index)=> {
          return(
            <View style={{margin:10}} key={index}>
              <Text>{d.name}</Text>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={showDatepicker}>
                <Text>{`${date.getDate()}/${date.getMonth() +1}/${date.getFullYear()}`}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              {show && (
                <DateTimePicker
                  testID="dateTimePicker"
                  value={date}
                  mode={mode}
                  is24Hour={true}
                  display="default"
                  onChange={onChange}
                />
              )}
            </View>
          )
        })
      }
    </View>
```

Comment: Remove datepicker outside your loop. You are creating a lot of datepicker instances.

Comment: I have multiple date from REST API so that's why i implemented in DateTimePicker inside loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try these.

```
const [dateList, setDateList] = useState([]);
const [showDates, setShowDates] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    setDateList([
      {Id: 1, name: 'ajay', date: '21/02/2021'},
      {Id: 2, name: 'vijay',date: '12/02/2022'},
      {Id: 3, name: 'zoya',date: '04/05/2023'},
    ]);
},[])

useEffect(() => {
    let dates = {};
    dateList.map((date,index) => {
        dates[date.Id]= false;
        if(index == 0)
            dates[date.Id] = true;
    })
    setShowDates(dates);
},[dateList])

const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    const currentDate = selectedDate;
    setDate(currentDate);
  };

const showDatepicker = (item) => {
   let dates = {};
   Object.keys(showDates).map(d => {
       dates[d.Id] = false;
   })
   dates[item.Id] = true;
   setShowDates(dates);
};

<View style={{marginTop:50}}>
      {
        dateList.map((d, index)=> {
          return(
            <View style={{margin:10}} key={index}>
              <Text>{d.name}</Text>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={showDatepicker.bind(this,d)}>
                <Text>{`${date.getDate()}/${date.getMonth() +1}/${date.getFullYear()}`}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              {showDates[d.Id]&& (
                <DateTimePicker
                  testID="dateTimePicker"
                  value={date}
                  mode={mode}
                  is24Hour={true}
                  display="default"
                  onChange={onChange}
                />
              )}
            </View>
          )
        })
      }
</View>
```

Comment: Jimbo Magusib has solved my problem and only one DateTimePicker is open at a time but the date changes everywhere.

Comment: you also have to change the value attribute in DateTimePicker according to your logic.